# Should I use "the" article or not?

Tags: articles

> 7,5 pounds! **Postage** is really high, could you lower it, **the postage** is higher than the single, will not buy it if you can't change it

Shall I use the article "the" or not in this sentence?

I am referring to postage due

Comment: Which **the**? The sentence has two, but there is a missing **the** which should be before "Postage is really high".

Comment: Improve by editing to give your reasoning. Why did you put "the" before the second "postage" but not before the first.  Also £7.50  or "seven pounds fifty" not 7,5 or even 7.5 pounds.

Comment: @JamesK: Is he referring to the weight of the mailpiece or its postage due?